# edit the file shared by Wifi Access Point

Tags: networking, samba, wireless-access-point

I recently found a tutorial http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/odroid-wifi-access-point-for-sharing-files-via-samba/
It taught me how to set up a wifi module in odroid board(installed ubuntu 14.04 and arm board), and my laptop can access the file in odroid board through the wifi.
I just wondering if I can edit those files (not the system files)?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the `writable = yes` line in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, as shown in the tutorial. You should be able to modify all files in the samba share location of `/mydrone/images`.

Something the guide doesn't mention is that you may need to reload your samba service to allow the changes to take effect. Do this with:

```
sudo service samba reload
```